# How to display Image saved in storage folder on blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, storage, laravel-blade

I would like to display an image saved in storage directory in a blade view. I am succesfully storing the file to the storage/app/public folder like so
ProfilesController file:

```
`if(request('image')) {
            $imagePath = request('image')->store('profile', 'public');

            $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1000, 1000);
            $image->save();
        }

        auth()->user()->profile->update(array_merge(
            $data,
            ['image' => $imagePath] 
        ));`
```

Now I would like to retrieve the image in my index.blade.php file. This is how  have done it:

`<img src="/storage/{{$user->profile->image}}" alt="">`

The laravel documentation says use storage link in my terminal I did this

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I tried all that but there is no image loading to the view!

What am I doing wrong and how to fix!

Comment: What does `{$user->profile->image}}` contain?

Answer (score 2):

```
    <img class="" src="{{ Storage::disk('name-option')->url('full path.jpg') }}"  alt="">
```

disk('name-option') is option you can skip as

```
<img class="" src="{{ Storage::url('full path.jpg') }}"  alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Accessor in the User Profile Model i.e:-

`public function getImageAttribute($image) { return asset('storage'.$image); }`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve it. The actual solution is on linking the storage directory with the public folder via the storage:link command as per the documentation
[enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

```
if(request('image')) {
       $imageName=time().'.' . $request->file('image')->extension();

        $imagePath = request('image')->storeAs('profile', $imageName);

        //you can use $imagePath to save the name as well as the path of the image
        $image->save();
    }

    ;`
```

In your filesystems.php file in the config folder, append the profile folder to match with the public folder like this:

```
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    public_path('profile') => storage_path('app/profile'),

],
```

Ensure you re-run the command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

In order to access the image,

```
<img src="{{asset($user->profile->image)}}" alt="">
```